# Can I change style of whole UL when hover over LI BUT make change specific to each individual LI

Tags: css, html-lists

I am writing a website in WordPress where I have created a child theme for the twentythirteen theme.

I am now trying to style the header navigation menu.

I would like to make it so that the text of each item in the menu changes to a different colour when you hover over it i.e. the text is all grey in it's normal state, but when you hover over menu item 1, the text of that link turns orange, when you hover over menu item 2, the text of that link turns green etc

I have achieved this fine, using css statements that target each individual item in the menu:

`li.menu-item-29:hover > a, .menu-item-29 a:focus {
    color: #00AEA1;
}`

However, I also have a style attached to the ul as a whole:

`ul.nav-menu, div.nav-menu > ul {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #D86637;
}`

This shows as a line underneath the whole menu. And I would like to make it so that when you hover over menu item 1, not only does the text of that item change to orange, but so does this underline affecting the whole ul change to orange too, and when you hover over menu item 2 not only does the text of that item change to green, but so does the underline affecting the whole ul change to green too etc

So, in summary, I am asking if it is possible, when hovering over each individual li in an ul, to change the border-bottom property of the whole ul, BUT make that change specific to which li has been hovered over.

Many thanks.

Comment: Currently you would need JavaScript for that. In future there may be a way like `ul:contains(li.identifier:hover)`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a shame - I don't have any JavaScript experience, so was hoping I might be able to do it just with css! If you have any tips on how to do it in JavaScript or where to start, I'd be so grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I'd consult the great tome of Google in this case.

Comment: Depending on how exactly your menu looks, this might be possible with CSS after all – take a look at this example, http://jsfiddle.net/f5k8S/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help offered.

I now have a solution that is based in css only, without the need for javascript.  As 'CBroe' suggested, the 'after' selector is the key - thank you very much.

Here is a link to the solution, that was provided to me on the Wordpress forums:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-style-of-whole-ul-when-hover-over-li-but-make-change-specific-to-each-li